# When iterating over hash, getting "TypeError: can't convert String into Integer"

Tags: ruby, typeerror

I have a hash (the real one is much bigger)

```
parsed = {"follower_count" => 500, "something_else" => "etc", "xyz" => "abc"}
```

and a class hanging around that looks like this

```
 class Company
   attr_accessor :followers

   def initialize(thehash)
      @followers = thehash['follower_count']
   end
 end
```

So lastly there is this code which throws the error before I can worry about anything else going wrong

```
>> parsed.map {|t| Company.new(t)}
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
  from (irb):7:in `[]'
  from (irb):7:in `initialize'
  from (irb):12:in `new'
  from (irb):12
  from (irb):12:in `map'
  from (irb):12:in `each'
  from (irb):12:in `map'
  from (irb):12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you iterate over a Hash, the block gets an array as its argument and that array contains (in order) the key and value for one pair in the Hash. So, in here:

```
parsed.map { |t| ... }
```

`t` is actually a two element array and is usually written:

```
parsed.map { |k, v| ... }
```

Then, inside `Company#initialize`, you're treating `t` as a Hash when it is actually a two element Array.

You don't want to use `map` on `parsed` at all, you just want to `Company.new(parsed)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `map` on a hash, you should use two variables in the block:

```
parsed.map {|k,v| .. use k and v here .. }
```

It doesn't seem like you want to iterate over `parsed` at all, you want to use it as the argument to `Company.new`:

```
Company.new(parsed)
```